# to fire after update trigger in mysql and insert that data in mongodb

Tags: mysql, mongodb, triggers, data-synchronization

want to create after update trigger in mysql  that can lead to saving that updated data in mongoDB. Do any one have any solution? It would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Tungsten replicator](http://pubs.vmware.com/continuent/tungsten-replicator-3.0/). If it is an overkill for your needs, you can write your own utility to process [MySQL binlog](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlbinlog.html).

In most cases, it is way simpler to apply this logic on the application layer, unless it is a 3rd party binary, and you don't have sources.